# Grouping records using shell

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to transform this:

```
1 Alice
1 Bob
1 Cary
2 Dan
3 Eve
3 Fred
```

into this:

```
1 Alice,Bob,Cary
2 Dan
3 Eve,Fred
```

using shell? (without Perl, Ruby, Python etc)

Comment: synapse, is this a school homework problem? It smells suspiciously like one, especially with the arbitrary limitation on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a few ways of doing this.

`Sort` is your friend: [Sort Wiki](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/sort-files-like-a-master-with-the-linux-sort-command-bash/).

As is `Awk`: [Awk Howto](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/05/group-similar-items-using-awk-array.html).

Comment: Jonathan, if he can't use perl/python, I'd rather assumed that all external utilities were banned.  I suspect it can be done in pure bash, but it looks so much like a homework exercise I decided not to bother.  Synapse, if this is a real problem, can you tell us a bit more about it, and which external tools **are** available to us?

Comment: @MadHatter We both read that question differently :-)

Comment: <LARGE GRIN> sorry, absolutely; I am in no way critical of your answer, and sort, awk (and sed) were the first tools my mind reached for as well, I think your recommendation is a good one.  I could do with a bit more information about the actual problem, is all!

Comment: @MadHatter Hehe :-)

Comment: @MadHatter The real thing is the output of md5sum | sort | uniq which was fed to Ruby for grouping and db processing. I was wondering what is possible without "real" programming languages.

Comment: @MadHatter Oh, actually it could've been my home assignment, but 1) ten years ago 2) csh 3) running on IBM PC/RT BSD. Good old days.

Answer (score 2):

Using associative arrays in bash version 4:

```sh
declare -A ary
while read line; do
  set -- $line
  ary[$1]+="$2,"
done < input_file
for key in ${!ary[@]}; do
  printf "%s %s\n" $key ${ary[$key]%,}  # the "%," strips the trailing comma
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Crap I couldn't resist the challenge.  Here's my solution in shell (bash to be exact) as a oneliner:

```
k=0; while read i j; do if [ $k -eq $i ]; then echo -n ",$j"; \
else [ $k -gt 0 ] && echo; echo -n "$i $j"; k=$i; fi; done \
</tmp/infile; echo
```

which produces the desired output, properly formatted:

```
1 Alice,Bob,Cary
2 Dan
3 Eve,Fred
```

Assumptions:

1. 0 is not a valid entry in the first column of the data.
2. the first column is already numerically sorted.

If #2 is not valid, you need to run the input through `sort(1)` first with a numeric sort to put it in the proper order.

If I find out I just answered your homework I will be extremely annoyed.  My only consolation is that if your teacher sees what I wrote they will think you are nuts.

Comment: No, that's not my homework. That's almost the last part of pipe to delete links to identical files in database wget/find/md5sum/sort/uniq/ruby. After I've written Ruby script to group and modify the db I was wondering if it's possible to do grouping using shell.

Comment: Just joking around, no offense meant.:)

Answer (score 0):

This one over at stackoverflow is very similar and has some good answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380817/best-way-to-simulate-group-by-from-bash

Comment: That counts single entries, so I don't think it's applicable.